# web3 deprecated - web3/ethjs etc. difference

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am currently working with smart contracts and the implementation and communication to web apps using MetaMask. I am now confused about what to use and how to implement it. What exactly will be deprecated? What and how should I use it now? Can you tell me an actual and not deprecated way/tutorial to connect to MetaMask, ask for balances and connect to contracts etc.?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with „web3 deprecated“?

Comment: "MetaMask: web3 will be deprecated in the near future in favor of the ethereumProvider 
https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md#web3-deprecation" I get that in the console.

Answer (score 3):

Web3 will not be deprecated,

I am not totally sure but as i understood this post :
https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md#deprecation-of-global-web3js

MetaMask and mist will stop injecting a `web3` global object as they do right now because it is chainging fast and a lot. they will instead inject an other API which is smaller and can let the users use a locally injected ( imported via code ) version of web3 or any other provider instead.

So you will be importing `web3` for example  :
`var web3 = require("web3");`

then you will integrating it with `MetaMask` by initializing the provider by the given provider (the `Ethereum Provider`) : `web3.setProvider(web3.currentProvider)`

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well smart contracts use events to communicate with the frontend. But, I suggest you start with the basics so learn how to call metamask using a button :
https://github.com/MetaMask/TipButton/blob/master/index.html

Then, you can learn how to use Remix to deploy your smart contract and play with it a bit :

https://remix.ethereum.org/

and finally you can try this tutorial :

https://coursetro.com/courses/20/Developing-Ethereum-Smart-Contracts-for-Beginners

I hope this would help a bit.
Best,
Tarik